# How do I use unique_together in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Model:

```
firstname: models.CharField(max_length = 30)
lastname: models.CharField(max_length = 30)
group: models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)
```

I like the concept of unique together but how do I use it?
What I want to do is apply the unique_together to firstname and group#
Later I will randomly assign group numbers and don't want there to be two first names in the same group so if it breaks the unique together rule, it tries the next group number. How do I apply this?

Comment: You add a `class Meta:` with `unique_together = ("firstname", "group")`.  See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the constraint is quite straight forward.
The tricky part for you is to create that one user if you randomly assign group numbers but no matter how you twist and turn it you would have a lot of SQL queries made since you need to check if user already exists.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    group = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("firstname", "group")
```

Then I guess something crude along the lines of (not tried and it's very "sloppy")

```
from random import randint
def assign_group_and_save():
    rand_group = randint(1, 99999)
    person, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(firstname=self.firstname, group=rand_group)
    if not created:
        #try again
        return self.assign_group_and_save()
    else:
        return person
```

That being said, I would look into trying to fork this task of to some async task using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and have that create your username for you instead of letting your user wait for you to return to her.

Comment: What if it didnt have to be random and their just couldn't be duplicates in the same group, would that ease it up?

Comment: When I think about it you could do this maybe, if you're using Django 1.6; 
`group = Group.objects.filter(~Q(user__firstname=firstname)).first(); group.user = user
`

Comment: That way you'll always get the first group that does NOT have the firstname of the user you have at hand.